# Could not resolve org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

The error I'm getting is:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'NaamaSmarane'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.1
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I can't take out mavenCentral() as that will throw a ton of other errors. Here's how my build.gradle looks like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
//        google()
//        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Would appreciate any help. I couldn't find a definitive answer to my issue in similar posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue finally got resolved by disabling the anti-virus software. Apparently, this was blocking access